# iOS 15.1 safari PWA statusbar color stays green despite changes in index.html and manifest.json

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

In buidling a `PWA` with `ionic` and `capacitor`. I've just updated my iPhone to `iOS 15.1`. When building for production, I noticed that the statusbar had a green color. I changed my `apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style` to `black-transculent`. Build the app again, added to home screen but still the status bar had a green color.

I inspected my `manifest.json` file and noticed that the `theme_color` property was set to `#4DBA87`. I looked this color up and it turned out to be the exact same color as the green color my statusbar has. Changed this color to `#FFFFFF` build the app again, added to home screen but still my statusbar stays the green color.

I'm a bit lost now what to do. I've made sure that after each build I cleared my cache to make sure the new build was loaded into `safari`. When I still had `iOS 14.7.x` the statusbar was white. I already looked up the release notes on `iOS 15.1` but it doesn't say anything about changes in `html` properties regarding `safari`.

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out thatmy `pwa` configuration settings in `vue.config.js` caused a 2x `<meta name="theme-color" />` tag in my `index.html`. the latter being the one with the green color, which was caused due to the fact that this tag was hard coded in my `index.html` and the `vue` `pwa` plugin also generated this tag, being the last one (order wise) with the green color.

I removed the hard coded tag, set the `themeColor` property in `vue.config.js` to `#FFFFFF` and all is well now.

`vue.config.js`:

```
pwa: {
    appleMobileWebAppCapable: 'yes',
    appleMobileWebAppStatusBarStyle: 'black-transculent',
    themeColor: '#FFFFFF'
}
```